# Can Windows 7 bootloader recognize WIndows 11?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, dualboot

I want to dual boot Windows 7 and Windows 11 on my laptop. My laptop is currently running Windows 11. Reinstalling Windows 11 is not an option because I have all my files on it.

So I need to know if the Windows 7 bootloader will recognize Windows 11?

Answer (score 2):

The strong likelihood is that a new Windows 11 machine will not run Windows 7. Some small number of machines might - most wont.

I do not see how Windows 11 will understand Windows 7 bootloader.  That approach will very most likely not work.

Best approach, given you do not wish to reinstall Windows 11 (understandable) is to run Windows 7 as a Virtual Machine. This will work - I have a working Windows 7 on my Windows 11 host machine